# Sublime Text 2 is using wrong PHP Version

Tags: php, python, sublimetext2, couchbase, pythonpath

I'm trying to test a class which involves a module installed in PHP 5.5 extension directory,  specifically Couchbase (which is running ok and I'm developing on top of it just fine in the same machine). But when php unit try to run the tests gives me an error saying the class Couchbase is not found, which is of course defined in the php sdk. I'm on MacOSX 10.7.3.

when I run in my terminal

```
tomas:~ tomasruiz$ php -v

PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2014 19:34:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

tomas:~ tomasruiz$ which php

/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

I created a plugin in Sublime Text 2 to see the php version used in sublime Text

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import subprocess
import os

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["php", "-v"]})
```

and this is what it returns...

```
PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  8 2011 19:34:00) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

and the same thing as above but with "which php" ..

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Someone has any idea on how to configure that? or what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

TR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean you're running php unit through ST build system? If that's so here's how I managed to fix a similar problem

**Solution 1:** Symlink

```
mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php53
ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

**Solution 2:** Edit or create a second build system for PHP

```
{ “cmd”: [“/usr/local/php5/bin/php”, “$file”], “file_regex”: “php$”, “selector”: “source.php” }
```

The problem you're facing is most likely caused by that the user under which ST runs PHP is not set up to use `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` executable, but the OS X built in old PHP 5.3 as `/usr/bin/` is the next place where system tries to find the executable, if it's not found in a local bin directory.

I suggest using solution 1 as that way you will be sure everything on your system is using the correct PHP version.

Comment: Thanks @Vlakarados, I'll try Solution 1 for sure, it is a little rough solution though. What do you mean by "the user under which ST runs PHP is not set up to use /usr/local/php5/bin/php executable", Is there a way to know what user is using? or a way to change it?.

Comment: It's rough if you need the old version, you may try running 'echo "$USER"' bash command from Sublime .py script